# Double quote issue with pasting a formula using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a Macro for a work project, and have come across an issue.

My goal is to paste a formula in cell B2 and have excel fill it down to the last row with anything in it, referencing column A. What I would like to paste is:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1),A2)
```

The formula is looking for the first space character in cell A2 (I use " " to mean a space) and to paste everything to the left of that space in the cell the formula is being typed in. Then I am filling it down. This is my code so far:

```
Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1),A2)"
```

I think that excel is thinking that I am ending the formula after the first double quote in the FIND function.

I have looked around a bit online and found people saying to use &CHR(34) to force excel to interpret a doublequote as a character but I think this is only for strings.

Does anyone know how to avoid this double quote issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA you need to double-up the quotes inside the string

```
Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("" "",A2)-1),A2)"
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I should have been able to figure that out... I feel dumb...